# Replacement for DWR

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, javascript, dwr

DWR is mainly used for handling AJAX responses from server..

So i wanted to know other similar technologies, which would make AJAX handling easy like calling a Java method from within Javascript and pasting the response in html code.

I know jQuery has AJAX methods, but so not think it can call and handle specific Java methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know jQuery has AJAX methods, but so not think it can call and
>   handle specific Java methods

I use spring with jquery, each request can be mapped to a specific method. I prefer it over dwr.

[Ajax and Spring.](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

Comment: Thx a lot..the main purpose i plan to use an AJAX library in my web app is i have a table/grid with dynamic data at diff places all getting filled by java/action class code output..Now in my case, i am returning the complete html table code as java code response..i want only the data to be returned and not the complete html..so pls suggest something based on this..

Answer (score 1):

You can give Google Web Toolkit a try, at this point it's mature enough to have all the decent features and no annoying bugs:

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/

Now GWT is not a straight out replacement for DWR. It's default usage is to have everything coded in Java (client UI and server side). This might be something prefferable to DWR's way of doing things. However if it's not, and you'd like to use GWT in a fashion more similar to DWR, you can have your javascript code / functions and your GWT Java classes, and you can call js functions from Java via GWT's JSNI API:

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: I've used GWT and found it more reliable than DWR

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)