# Is it possible to create image in jquery function using Java code?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf

I want to create an image file (.jpg, .png) using a jQuery function.
In the application we are using JSF as view Page. How to create an image using jQuery when the function is called from Java method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545898/jquery-ajax-to-call-java-method

Comment: Do you want to generate an image in server side and show it on the client?

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev... yes I want to generate image in server side and show it on client

Comment: @Vash... In your link that i know but hoiw to create image using jQuery Function ???