# How to call a method in a different java class inside javascript

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, jsp

I'm having an application which takes input from a popup dialog.When a user enters a text in the text field of a popup dialog.I need to pass that text to another method ina different class.How can I achieve this. My code is shown below.

viewRoles.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html"  import="com.model.Data" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <link href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script>
          window.onload=function()
          {
                var el=document.getElementById('btnAddNewRole');
                el.onclick=function()
                {
                var my_text=prompt('Enter text here');
                if(my_text){
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '/com.model/Data/addRole('+my_text+')',
                    success: function(my_text){
                    alert("Inserted")
                    }, error: function(){
                    // when got error
                    }
                    });
                }
                }
          }
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>View Roles</title>
    </head>
    <body><br><br>
           <button id="btnAddNewRole" class="btn btn-info">Add New Role</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Data.java in com.model package

```
package com.model;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.hibernate.Session;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Data {
    private Roles r;
    private HibernateUtil helper;
    private Session session;

    public void addRole(String roleTitle){
        r=new Roles(roleTitle);
        session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(r);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can ! ajax map to an URL who your js function will get into your `addRole` methode ? you need to use a mapping in your server side.

Comment: @AtimeneNazim How can I achieve this task can you please guide me, Your answer is not quite understandable to me

Comment: you need to put an url into your server side. this way your client (ajax call) can reach the method.

Comment: Do you have controllers ?

Comment: @AtimeneNazim No actually I'm sending data to db using Data.java class,Here You have said 'put an url into your server side' can you please guide me what it really means I didn't get it yet.I'm very beginner to programming.Thanks in advance

Comment: here's a good discussion about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545898/jquery-ajax-to-call-java-method